# JSON payload construction Android

Tags: java, android, json

I want to construct a JSON payload of this:

```
{
    "aps": {
         "badge": 15,
         "alert": "Hello from Urban Airship!",
         "sound": "cat.caf"
    }
}
```

I tried with this thing :

```
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        JSONObject badge=new JSONObject();
        JSONObject alert=new JSONObject();
        JSONObject sound=new JSONObject();


        badge.put("badge",15);
        json.put("aps",badge);
        sound.put("sound",getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cat));
        json.put("aps",alert);
        alert.put("alert", "Hello from Uday!");
        json.put("aps",sound);
```

but it full payload is obtaining:when I print

am getting like half of payload like this:

`{"aps":{"sound":"cat.caf"}}`

its overriding, but

How do it in a correct way

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are looking for, but considering that you want to create a JSON String.

```
     try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject aps = new JSONObject();

            aps.put("badge", 15);
            aps.put("alert", "Hello from Urban Airship!");
            aps.put("sound", "cat.caf");
            Log.d("my json string", json.put("aps", aps).toString(1));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: AM getting the wrong order, will tht be a problem am getting bad request error: {
        "aps": {
            
             "alert": "Hello from Urban Airship!",
             "sound": "cat.caf", "badge": 15
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

`openRawResource()` returns an `InputStream`.. you might want to try reading it using an `InputStreamReader`?